# Read excel, search for and replace pieces of text in web C# application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, excel-interop

I have an excel file, need access, replace parts of the text and download the changed file.
But I can not save the changes, I should always keep the version on the server.

I did several searches, but I can only change the file and save the changes.

I tried to solve with the link below, I managed to search and change the file, but I do not know how to download and stop saving the changes.

[Find and replace text in Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484841/find-and-replace-text-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into a memory stream. Do your changes and write it to a byte array. Use the byte array `bytesInstream` to download and the original file remains unaltered.

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("excelFile.xlsx");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (SpreadsheetDocument  doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
    {
       // Do work here
    }
    // Convert it to byte array 
    byte[] bytesInStream = ms.ToArray();
}
```

I have assumed you are using openxml to make your changes.

Comment: To replace text in excel using openxml you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719193/openxml-excel-how-to-change-value-of-a-cell-when-value-is-in-sharedstringtable) post. Note the shared string table only holds text that is inserted into cells. If you need to change text present in text boxes, charts, wordarts you need to fetch for it under the drawing xml.